# Rails fuzzy searching on title and description

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, full-text-search, fuzzy-search

I have a simple rails 3 application that lists restaurants as a training exercise. I want to be able to search name and description using one textfield on the restaurant index page.

Given the query **pizza**. The matches should be

- name: Tony's, description: ... is a pizzeria that has been around since the 1950's ...
- name: Domino's Pizza, description: ...
- name: The Hall, description: ... pizzas, pastas and steaks ...

Because:

1. the word pizza is a **fuzzy** match to " **pizz** eri **a** " using similar logic as TextMate's Cmd-T. (the spaces in the word pizzeria are only used to get the mini-Markdown to work)
2. pizza is a **lowercase** match to Pizza
3. pizza is a **substring** of pizzas (should work with ends-with begins-with and includes)

How would I go about doing this in rails 3? Do I use thinking_sphinx, tire, sunspot-rails or just a custom query for my application.

Comment: I have had success with this in the past by just using `LIKE %pizza%` in a scope. E.g. `name LIKE %pizza% OR description LIKE %pizza%`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a very simple solution that serves my needs.

```
"%#{"pizza".scan(/./).join("%")}%"
```

This creates a string that looks like this

```
"%p%i%z%z%a%"
```

Then I use it in a LIKE query and I get the expected results. Now all that remains is to solve the non-trivial problem of determining the order of relevance :)

UPDATE:

Found a quick and dirty way of determining order of relevance base on the assumption that a shorter string will most likely be a closer match than a longer one.

```
ORDER BY length(sequence) ASC
```

Comment: This method might work but you will get false positives and it won't perform nearly as well.

Answer (score 1):

The only tricky one is pizza/pizzeria and it's an issue called stemming.

Both sphinx and solr/sunspot support stemming but I imagine you will need to teach them both that pizza is a stem of pizzeria.

Comment: I was thinking of a more language independent solution like the one that Sublime and TextMate use to find files. E.g.

rcon => app/controllers/ **r** estaurants_ **con** troller.rb

Comment: That's really a different issue from stemming. In other words, pizza* will match pizzas but it won't match pizzeria.

Answer (score 1):

One way to remove false positives is to run a user defined function (UDF) to compute the edit distance between a candidate answer and the original string, and ignore those answers whose edit distance is too large.